# Cursor in select element of electron app captured

Tags: javascript, html, electron

We are working on an electron web app.

In our pages we are using input, textarea and select tags, which have - among others - the tabindex attribute to make correct tab navigation possible.

The indeces are always starting with 1.

In input and textarea tags the tab navigation works but not with select tags.

Unfortunately the dropdownlist of a select in electron opens when you click on the element - not just when you click the arrow-button on the right edge of the element - and then the cursor seems to be captured.

Pushing the tab-key has no effect anymore.

Is there a trick to make tab navigation possible even with select tags?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Unfortunately the dropdownlist of a select in electron opens when you click on the element` that is exactly how it *should* behave.

Comment: Also, this sounds odd, given that it just uses a regular browser rendering engine.